# How to pass arguments using command line when launching Tomcat server?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, arguments

I'm using **Tomcat server** and **Jersey** library.

I want to pass one argument as the file path, use said path to open a specific file and then use the contents of this file in my `@GET` or `@POST` method.

Something like:

```
./server --config="File path or URL here"
```

How can I achieve the effect of passing the command line arguments to the `args[]` variable in main method?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat has a dedicated file for passing arguments to the JVM, it is the file called `setenv.sh`. You can read the reference [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt).